# Error while loading csv to D3.js through localhost

Tags: html, d3.js, localhost

I have the code below to produce a d3 animation.
The problem is that my data is not loading properly.
My csv is located at Desktop at a folder called Data and I would like to it through localhost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    text{
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    }
    text.title{
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
      text.subTitle{
        font-weight: 500;
        fill: #777777;
      }
      text.caption{
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        fill: #777777;
      }
      text.label{
        font-weight: 600;
      }

      text.valueLabel{
       font-weight: 300;
      }

      text.yearText{
        font-size: 64px;
        font-weight: 700;
        opacity: 0.25;
      }
      .tick text {
        fill: #777777;
      }
      .xAxis .tick:nth-child(2) text {
        text-anchor: start;
      }
      .tick line {
        shape-rendering: CrispEdges;
        stroke: #dddddd;
      }
      .tick line.origin{
        stroke: #aaaaaa;
      }
      path.domain{
        display: none;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // Feel free to change or delete any of the code you see in this editor!
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 600);



    var tickDuration = 500;

    var top_n = 12;
    var height = 600;
    var width = 960;

    const margin = {
      top: 80,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 5,
      left: 0
    };

    let barPadding = (height-(margin.bottom+margin.top))/(top_n*5);

    let title = svg.append('text')
     .attr('class', 'title')
     .attr('y', 24)
     .html('Fertility Rate 1960 - 2017');

    let subTitle = svg.append("text")
     .attr("class", "subTitle")
     .attr("y", 55)
     .html("Average");

    let caption = svg.append('text')
     .attr('class', 'caption')
     .attr('x', width)
     .attr('y', height-5)
     .style('text-anchor', 'end')
     .html('Source: Interbrand');

     let year = 1960;


http://localhost:8000/Desktop/Data/fertility_final.csv.then(function(data) {



      console.log(data);

       data.forEach(d => {
        d.value = +d.value,
        d.lastValue = +d.lastValue,
        d.value = isNaN(d.value) ? 0 : d.value,
        d.year = +d.year,
        d.colour = d3.hsl(Math.random()*360,0.75,0.75)
      });

     console.log(data);

     let yearSlice = data.filter(d => d.year == year && !isNaN(d.value))
      .sort((a,b) => b.value - a.value)
      .slice(0, top_n);

      yearSlice.forEach((d,i) => d.rank = i);

     console.log('yearSlice: ', yearSlice)

     let x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(yearSlice, d => d.value)])
        .range([margin.left, width-margin.right-65]);

     let y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([top_n, 0])
        .range([height-margin.bottom, margin.top]);

     let xAxis = d3.axisTop()
        .scale(x)
        .ticks(width > 500 ? 5:2)
        .tickSize(-(height-margin.top-margin.bottom))
        .tickFormat(d => d3.format(',')(d));

     svg.append('g')
       .attr('class', 'axis xAxis')
       .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${margin.top})`)
       .call(xAxis)
       .selectAll('.tick line')
       .classed('origin', d => d == 0);

     svg.selectAll('rect.bar')
        .data(yearSlice, d => d.name)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', x(0)+1)
        .attr('width', d => x(d.value)-x(0)-1)
        .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5)
        .attr('height', y(1)-y(0)-barPadding)
        .style('fill', d => d.colour);

     svg.selectAll('text.label')
        .data(yearSlice, d => d.name)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('x', d => x(d.value)-8)
        .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1)
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .html(d => d.name);

    svg.selectAll('text.valueLabel')
      .data(yearSlice, d => d.name)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'valueLabel')
      .attr('x', d => x(d.value)+5)
      .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1)
      .text(d => d3.format(',.0f')(d.lastValue));

    let yearText = svg.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'yearText')
      .attr('x', width-margin.right)
      .attr('y', height-25)
      .style('text-anchor', 'end')
      .html(~~year)
      .call(halo, 10);

   let ticker = d3.interval(e => {

      yearSlice = data.filter(d => d.year == year && !isNaN(d.value))
        .sort((a,b) => b.value - a.value)
        .slice(0,top_n);

      yearSlice.forEach((d,i) => d.rank = i);

      //console.log('IntervalYear: ', yearSlice);

      x.domain([0, d3.max(yearSlice, d => d.value)]); 

      svg.select('.xAxis')
        .transition()
        .duration(tickDuration)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .call(xAxis);

       let bars = svg.selectAll('.bar').data(yearSlice, d => d.name);

       bars
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', d => `bar ${d.name.replace(/\s/g,'_')}`)
        .attr('x', x(0)+1)
        .attr( 'width', d => x(d.value)-x(0)-1)
        .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
        .attr('height', y(1)-y(0)-barPadding)
        .style('fill', d => d.colour)
        .transition()
          .duration(tickDuration)
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5);

       bars
        .transition()
          .duration(tickDuration)
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .attr('width', d => x(d.value)-x(0)-1)
          .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5);

       bars
        .exit()
        .transition()
          .duration(tickDuration)
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .attr('width', d => x(d.value)-x(0)-1)
          .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
          .remove();

       let labels = svg.selectAll('.label')
          .data(yearSlice, d => d.name);

       labels
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('x', d => x(d.value)-8)
        .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2))
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .html(d => d.name)    
        .transition()
          .duration(tickDuration)
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1);


       labels
          .transition()
          .duration(tickDuration)
            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .attr('x', d => x(d.value)-8)
            .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1);

       labels
          .exit()
          .transition()
            .duration(tickDuration)
            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .attr('x', d => x(d.value)-8)
            .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
            .remove();



       let valueLabels = svg.selectAll('.valueLabel').data(yearSlice, d => d.name);

       valueLabels
          .enter()
          .append('text')
          .attr('class', 'valueLabel')
          .attr('x', d => x(d.value)+5)
          .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
          .text(d => d3.format(',.0f')(d.lastValue))
          .transition()
            .duration(tickDuration)
            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1);

       valueLabels
          .transition()
            .duration(tickDuration)
            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .attr('x', d => x(d.value)+5)
            .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1)
            .tween("text", function(d) {
               let i = d3.interpolateRound(d.lastValue, d.value);
               return function(t) {
                 this.textContent = d3.format(',')(i(t));
              };
            });


      valueLabels
        .exit()
        .transition()
          .duration(tickDuration)
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .attr('x', d => x(d.value)+5)
          .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
          .remove();

      yearText.html(~~year);

     if(year == 2018) ticker.stop();
     year = d3.format('.1f')((+year) + 0.1);
   },tickDuration);

 });

 const halo = function(text, strokeWidth) {
  text.select(function() { return this.parentNode.insertBefore(this.cloneNode(true), this); })
    .style('fill', '#ffffff')
     .style( 'stroke','#ffffff')
     .style('stroke-width', strokeWidth)
     .style('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
     .style('opacity', 1);

}   


  </script>
</body>
```

When I check on console, I'm getting error below

```
Uncaught TypeError: "http://localhost:8000/Desktop/Dat/fertility_final.csv".then is not a function
    at chart.html:99
```

I do realize the error is because of wrong formatting of the line loading data.

Thoughts on how to put the line so it loads correctly?

My localhost is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the data like this:

```
d3.csv("/data/fertility_final.csv").then(function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

But the file must be on your localhost folder. If you use xampp, for example, it should be at `C:/xampp/htdocs/your_site/data/fertility_final.csv`.

"But why can't I access it on my Desktop through localhost?"

Your localhost only hosts a folder and its children, e.g. `C:/xampp/htdocs/*`.